# Declension and case confusion in sentence

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

**Sentence:** "Wenn Sie fertig sind, legen Sie die Karte verdeckt auf den Tisch und schieben Sie der Person ihrer Rechten zu"

**Question:** in the last part of the sentence, why is it it "Ihrer Rechten" and not "Ihr Recht". I cannot understand the declension rules for these two words. If I understand correctly, "der Person" is the indirect object here and "ihrer" is referring back to the subject "Sie". I'm confused about what case applies to "Ihrer Rechten" and why it is declined in this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please be aware, that the last _Sie_ is not the subject ("_you_"), but refers to _the card_ (and must therefore be written with a lowercase _s_):
_Wenn Sie fertig sind, legen Sie die Karte verdeckt auf den Tisch und schieben sie der Person ihrer Rechten zu_

Comment: Check your source, because something else could be a missing *zu*, so "und schieben [Sie] sie der Person **zu** Ihrer Rechten zu" could be the full  subordinate clause.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I agree with both. This is a dialogue from the movie Inglorious Basterds and the source is https://subslikescript.com/movie/Inglourious_Basterds-361748. It is from the card game scene between the German major and the undercover British Captain. It could be a wrong transcription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full translation is:

> If you are finished, place the card on the table with its face side downwards and shift it to the person on your right (hand) side.

So the missing lowercase *sie* means the card (accusative object), *Person* refers to whoever sits on your right side (dative object), and *zu Ihrer Rechten* is a location of that *Person* given in its usual dative, similar as it would be *auf Ihrer rechten Seite*.

One could also consider the person also as location, but targets of giving are always *dative* anyway.

Comment: Agreed. So, am I right to assume that "der Person zu ihrer Rechten" is a location in itself (if we add another zu), as it is where the card is being moved to? That would also explain why the declension for Person is der (Dativ) and not die (Akkusativ). Or am I wrong again? xD

Comment: @Shaurya: Correct, I tried to clarify this in the text

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot